# Mobile SDK - illegalState("CentralManager was nil")

Tags: tapkey

I use Tapkey Mobile SDK v '2.19.1.0'. It works fine most of the time. I can trigger the lock. But sometimes (no pattern defined) I get this logs for trying to trigger the lock

```
2021-12-06 15:00:52.833160-0500 Lattis Dev[1972:776947] [general] BleLockCommunicatorImpl: failed to establish BLE connection - retrying
2021-12-06 15:00:54.845694-0500 Lattis Dev[1972:776947] [general] BleLockCommunicatorImpl: failed to establish BLE connection - giving up
2021-12-06 15:00:54.849022-0500 Lattis Dev[1972:776947] [general] BleLockCommunicatorImpl: BLE communication sequence w/o connect took 1.638820854848E9 ms.
illegalState("CentralManager was nil") TapkeyMobileLib.TKMAsyncError
```

And trigger doesn't work until I restart the app.

Answer (score 1):

The Tapkey App SDK for iOS requires that during Communication the Ble Scanning is running.

It seems, that in such cases, the scanning was already stopped.